# Why fail2ban would ban an IP that is whitelisted (on ignoreip)?

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I have fail2ban configured to protect the authentication on a postfix service.
The jail is working properly on the ban side, but the `ignoreip` option seems to be ignored or misconfigured since it bans IP's that are under the specified CIDRs:

This is the jail:

```
[postfix-sasl]
enabled = true
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
filter = postfix-sasl
action_mwl = iptables-allports[name=postfix-sasl]
logpath = /var/log/zimbra.log
bantime = 3600
maxretry = 3
```

This is an example of a banned IP under one of the CIDRs specified on the `ignoreip` option (192.168.0.0/16):

```
Chain f2b-postfix-sasl (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  192.168.11.54        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

This are the lines matching this IP on the `/var/log/fail2ban/log`:

```
2019-03-21 09:21:33,269 fail2ban.filter         [32293]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 192.168.11.54
2019-03-21 09:21:48,290 fail2ban.filter         [32293]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 192.168.11.54
2019-03-21 09:21:49,044 fail2ban.actions        [32293]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Ban 192.168.11.54
```

I can see on the [fail2ban wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_spanish) that the `ignoreip` can accept space separated values and CIDR notations, from the fail2ban wiki:

```
# Option: ignoreip.
# Notes.: space separated list of IP's to be ignored by fail2ban..
# You can use CIDR mask in order to specify a range..
# Example: ignoreip = 192.168.0.1/24 123.45.235.65.
# Values: IP Default: 192.168.0.0/24.
#.
ignoreip = 192.168.1.0/24
```